# openstack pacemaker-schedulerd error

Tags: openstack, pacemaker

I have noticed this problem in the syslog and i'm not sure how to resolve this. I have openstack yoga with ubuntu 22.04 `selfservice` network option.

I have 1 controller node and 1 compute node

```
Dec  5 22:12:44 controller1 pacemaker-controld[1467]:  notice: State transition S_IDLE -> S_POLICY_ENGINE 
Dec  5 22:12:44 controller1 pacemaker-schedulerd[1462]:  error: Resource start-up disabled since no STONITH resources have been defined
Dec  5 22:12:44 controller1 pacemaker-schedulerd[1462]:  error: Either configure some or disable STONITH with the stonith-enabled option
Dec  5 22:12:44 controller1 pacemaker-schedulerd[1462]:  error: NOTE: Clusters with shared data need STONITH to ensure data integrity
Dec  5 22:12:44 controller1 pacemaker-schedulerd[1462]:  notice: Delaying fencing operations until there are resources to manage
Dec  5 22:12:44 controller1 pacemaker-schedulerd[1462]:  notice: Calculated transition 1088, saving inputs in /var/lib/pacemaker/pengine/pe-input-2.bz2
Dec  5 22:12:44 controller1 pacemaker-schedulerd[1462]:  notice: Configuration errors found during scheduler processing,  please run "crm_verify -L" to identify issues
Dec  5 22:12:44 controller1 pacemaker-controld[1467]:  notice: Transition 1088 (Complete=0, Pending=0, Fired=0, Skipped=0, Incomplete=0, Source=/var/lib/pacemaker/pengine/pe-input-2.bz2): Complete
Dec  5 22:12:44 controller1 pacemaker-controld[1467]:  notice: State transition S_TRANSITION_ENGINE -> S_IDLE
```

Comment: You do not have configured fencing. Either disable it or configure it if applicable. Check 
 in the documentation [link](https://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/doc/2.1/Clusters_from_Scratch/html/fencing.html).

Comment: @dexter do you know where this is mentioned in openstack docs?

Comment: It looks like cluster is configured with pacemaker and I believe that pacemaker can be treated independent on rest of the setup. I do not know the details but I just gave you the idea and direction. Hope that it is helpful.